# Understanding PARALLAX scrolling effect - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have this test page which I torture with my very basic JS skills.
I am currently working on another, more serious project and I saw a nice [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TawH-AqHTXc&t=6s) on Youtube about the *Parallax scrolling effect*, so I thought it would be nice to implement this in the more *serious* project.

**1. I will ask you if I understood the code correctly**

**2. I will ask you what a portion of that code means**

**Here's the code:**

```
    let paral = document.querySelector('.paral');
let bubble = document.querySelector('.bubble');
let burgerimage = document.querySelector('.burgerimage');
let ximage = document.querySelector('.ximage');


window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let curr = window.scrollY;

  bubble.style.left = curr * 0.5 + 'px';
  burgerimage.style.right = curr * .5 + 'px';
  ximage.style.bottom = curr * 3 + 'px';
})
```

***1. Understanding the code:**

If I got it right, this line for example `bubble.style.left = curr * 0.5 + 'px';` means:

*Take the bubble variable and move it from the left at half the speed of the scrolling speed.* **Is this right?**

***2. Here's the question:**

I don't understand: `'px'`. If I cancel it, of course the effect doesn't work anymore.

Why is there and what it means?

**The snippet**

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');


burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
});

const xicon = document.querySelector('.xicon');
xicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
})



const header = document.querySelector('header');
let prev = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  let current = window.pageYOffset;

  if(prev < current){
    header.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    header.classList.remove('hide');
    }

    prev = current;

})


const shareThing = document.querySelector('.share');
let prevScroll = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if(prevScroll < currentScroll) {
    shareThing.classList.add('hide');
    icons.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    shareThing.classList.remove('hide');
    icons.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  prevScroll = currentScroll;

})


let share = document.querySelector('.share');
let icons = document.querySelector('.side');

share.addEventListener('click', () => {
  icons.classList.toggle('active');
})




let paral = document.querySelector('.paral');
let bubble = document.querySelector('.bubble');
let burgerimage = document.querySelector('.burgerimage');
let ximage = document.querySelector('.ximage');


window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let curr = window.scrollY;

  bubble.style.left = curr * 0.5 + 'px';
  burgerimage.style.right = curr * .5 + 'px';
  ximage.style.bottom = curr * 3 + 'px';
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logoandicon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: powderblue;
  padding: .7em 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.burger {
  margin-right: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burger.hide {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  padding: 1em 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: none;
}

nav.active {
  display: block;
}

.xicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.xicon.active {
  display: block;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}

header.hide {
  display: none;
}

main {
  padding-top: 5em;
}

.one {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.two {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.three {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.side {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.side.active {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
}

.side.hide {
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.share {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  padding: .15em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 3;
}

.share.hide {
  margin-left: -35px;
}

.paral {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  position: relative;
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
}

.burgerimage {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.ximage {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logoandicon">
      <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      <img src="menu.svg" class="burger" width="30px" alt="burger-icon">
      <img src="xicon.svg" class="xicon" width="27px" alt="x-icon">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>

    <p class="share">Share</p>
    <div class="side">
      <div class="one">Fb</div>
      <div class="two">Ig</div>
      <div class="three">Tw</div>
    </div>

    <div class="paral">
      <img src="bubble.svg" width="100px" class="bubble" alt="bubbles">
      <img src="menu.svg" width="100px" class="burgerimage" alt="burgericon">
      <img src="xicon.svg" width="100px" class="ximage" alt="xicon">
    </div>

    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ut, animi iure sequi voluptatem maiores, aspernatur tempora, ipsa tempore, voluptate sint. Maiores quos inventore cumque reiciendis iusto illum, aut quam, suscipit temporibus veniam. Reprehenderit distinctio velit eveniet blanditiis, animi optio voluptas dolores repellendus ad itaque veritatis. Expedita deserunt, ab dolor accusamus sequi eum optio. Fuga dolorum, quod qui laboriosam iure molestiae magnam explicabo! Accusamus, alias, non. Eius voluptas in aspernatur natus illo et possimus optio, cupiditate saepe quisquam totam laboriosam ullam nihil consequatur rem earum ratione perspiciatis. Quo impedit ipsum assumenda suscipit unde inventore dolores quas? Ipsa aliquam sapiente rerum sit autem magni ad dolore iste vero optio saepe, impedit eveniet suscipit, deserunt. Modi architecto laudantium placeat beatae repellat harum deleniti facere deserunt officia unde mollitia error praesentium, sunt fugit recusandae soluta facilis earum voluptatem libero consectetur illum debitis quos! Odit unde, quo non blanditiis vitae aperiam obcaecati provident praesentium quas qui, veritatis enim accusamus iusto rerum harum porro maxime sit amet cum odio suscipit ipsum nulla adipisci. Totam consectetur quas ipsa. Natus officiis, eveniet reprehenderit neque rem sint eum, ratione, numquam blanditiis nisi culpa repudiandae nemo beatae. Ea cum officiis vel, sed distinctio, voluptatibus quibusdam! Soluta voluptate, non facilis?</h1>
  </main>


<script src="main.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> If I got it right, this line for example `bubble.style.left = curr * 0.5 + 'px';` means:
>
> Take the bubble variable and move it from the left at half the speed of the scrolling speed. Is this right?

<s>No, `bubble.style.left = curr * 0.5 + 'px';` does not mean that.</s> `element.style.` is used to apply a CSS property. For example, `element.style.left` will change the CSS `left` property of `element`.

*Edit:* About the "speed" of "the bubble": it will indeed move at half the "speed" of scrolling. As it is defined based on a fraction (0.5 here) of [Window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY). *The read-only scrollY property of the Window interface returns the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically*. Read my comment on this answer for more clarity.

> I don't understand: 'px'. If I cancel it, of course the effect doesn't work anymore.
>
> Why is there and what it means?

While setting a CSS property, you need to mention what unit you are using. So to specify

```
element {
  left: 4px;
}
```

you need to write this code

```js
element.style.left = 4 + 'px'
```

If you still have problems, you probably need to learn CSS.
Check out [ElementCSSInlineStyle on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style).

Comment: Thank you, but you didn't answer to my first question. I think 'curr * 0.5' DOES mean the velocity of the moving element based on the scrolling velocity, because if I set it to 'curr * 3' it moves much faster.

Comment: It does not mean to control the speed of the moving element. Every time the window scrolls the code changes the `left` style of the element to `0.5` times the length window has scrolled. As a byproduct, it appears that the velocity of the element is being changed. When it is changed to 3 it moves three times the distance of the scrolled distance. Technically it is not directly changing the speed but since scientifically change is distance is velocity, it is correct to say that the code changes the velocity.

Comment: You should accept the answer which solved your question.